Source of "A priest can say three heresies in a sermon but must not insist on them"?
I was said that some pope of last centuries wrote a document where he stated this idea:
"A priest can say three heresies in a sermon but must not insist on them." I have a suspicion that I have seen that somewhere, but I cannot remember now where it was?
Can you help my poor memory? :-)
Thanks

Welcome, I'm not sure why your question was downvoted, except that someone perhaps thought you should do this research yourself. I voted it back up to zero. Have you tried to google that exact phrase in quotations? That will sometimes pull up useful sources.

I was searching for that many times. Even AI and got a confused answer that the author is Gregory the Great  in his Regula pastoralis but with completely wrong citation.

Maybe a pope didn't write this but just said it in a sermon, as one of his three heresies.

Dear Mr. Blass, of course it could be almost anywhere - I am looking here for those who are smarter than me. :-)

I would very much like to know the answer to this question, so I've opened a bounty on it.

As a non-Roman Catholic, I'm not familiar with this phrase. Can someone edit the original question to include its meaning. I don't think it should be assumed (for the sake of a good question on stack exchange).
